# Unit Test the Android Notification

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, push-notification, android-pendingintent

I'm testing my Android App and I wanted to test that depending on the JSON the server is sending, the system was creating the notifications I was expecting.

For instance, I have tests like this:

```
public void testCustomIconAndLinkNotification() throws Exception {
    String title = "title";
    String message = "message";
    String json = "{\n" +
            "      \"android_background_data\": true,\n" +
            "      \"__title\": \"" + title + "\",\n" +
            "      \"message\": \"" + message + "\",\n" +
            "      \"imageUrl\": \"nothing\",\n" +
            "      \"link\": \"nothing\"\n" +
            "    }";
    Notification n = osbnr.createNotificationFromServerData(getInstrumentation().getContext(), new JSONObject(json));
    Bundle b = n.extras;
    assertEquals(title, b.get("android.title"));
    assertEquals(message, b.get("android.text"));
}
```

It's actually working even though it is a bit hacky. However I encounter lots of security issue because the process doing the test is not the same as the one running the app and it's creating `Security Exception`

As, for instance, here:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() from pid=9487, uid=10373, (need uid=10374) is not allowed to send as package mypackage.test
>   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
>   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
>   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerNative.java:4039)
>   at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:312)

Because I'm trying to create `Pending Intent` to put as `Action` in my notifications:

```
PendingIntent linkPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 2, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

My question would be:

> Regarding the hackyness of the test I currently have, I'd like to know if there is a decent way to test that the notifications are correctly created and displayed or should we just "hope and pray"?